# Why does the zoom on my Canon T3i not work?

Tags: zoom, canon-600d

I have a new Canon T3i and was able to take and capture zoomed in photos
with the lens that came with the camera(EF-S 18-55mm) as well as a Canon Zoom Lens EF 75-300mm  1:4-5.6.  Now when I zoom in with either lense and take a photo when I review it,it shows original image before zooming. Is it a defect in the camera or inexperience with the operator.